# Can MySQL MASTER Server also work as SLAVE?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have set up Replication Between SERVER A to SERVER B AND ALSO SERVER C. So Server A is the MASTER and SERVER B/C are both SLAVES OF A.

Is there a way WHERE I can also set up server A to be the SLAVE for Server B AND B is the MASTER OF A?

Thank you

Comment: This should be on DBA

Comment: sorry, but what is DBA?

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com a sister site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I did it before. look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication)

Comment: Nice. So it is the same method of replication MASTER-SLAVE but applying the steps on the slave as in master. Did you face any performance issues when doing that?

Comment: Yep, do it in the same way except changing the ip, mysql-bin, position, etc. I do the MATER-MASTER for hot backup. As to performance, I think MASTER-SLAVE is better, you can split the writing and reading, the slave is only for reading(except from slave threads or from users having the SUPER privilege). So I employ the Master-Mater-Slave.

Comment: I have MySQL installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 it seems that the setup is slightly different. I don't see any on the 4 variables in my.ini file. I am not sure how to do this. but when I did SHOW MASTER STATUS; i get no results. any hints?

Comment: The 4 variables is not in the configure file, they are in the command: 'CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'IP', MASTER_USER = 'user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.00000x', MASTER_LOG_POS = XXX'. MySQL shows "Empty Set" for SHOW MASTER STATUS, maybe your binary logging was not enabled. execute command 'show binary logs', show me the result.

Comment: in order to execute the CHANGE MASTER TO..... I need to know the log file information. I executed show binary logs and I got the following. ERROR 1381 You are not using binary logging

Comment: binary logging is required for replication. You can enable that by adding a line 'log-bin=mysql-bin' to you configure file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36432/discussion-between-jfly-and-mike)